# Why is my regex failing on on certain strings that otherwise succeed?

Tags: regex, f#, .net-5

I have code written in F# that iterates over an array of strings using regex to extract part of those strings. The problem is that the regex appears to randomly successfully match on some, but fail on others, even on an exact duplicates from the same list where it previously succeeded. What am I missing? Is this some sort of regex issue that I am not aware of?

Regex Pattern:

```
(?i)/(.*?/v\d/.*?((?=\?)|(?=\d)|(?=\n)))
```

F# code:

```
[<Literal>]
    let ApiPattern = @"(?i)/(.*?/v\d/.*?((?=\?)|(?=\d)|(?=\n)))"

let parseOutEndpoints (inputs : (int * string) array) =
    let regEx = new Regex(ApiPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)

    inputs |> Array.map (fun (id, path) -> [|id.ToString(); path|]) |> Array.collect (fun x -> x)
    |> writeRawPathsToFile

    File.ReadAllLines(RawPathsFile)
    |> Array.map(fun (x) -> 
        let m = regEx.Match(x)

        if m.Success
        then 
            let endpoint = Domain.Endpoint(m.Value)
            endpoint
        else
            let line = $"{x}"
            File.AppendAllLines(FailedRegexMatches, [line], Encoding.UTF8)
            Domain.NoEndpoint
    )
```

**Sample string array Data:**
All of these should return a match, but don't. In comparison to this original list, a significantly reduced list of successful matches will be returned.

```
/enterprise-review/v9/choose?rr=Straight&pr=1%2E35239
/review-id-service/v1/business-id
/orderout/v1/vendor/shipping
/vendor-service/v1/Product/PartnerId/35310108
/Inspect/v1/Recommendation/Products/LaneId/0002,519188,13148,16939,7348,195982
/bin-inventory/v1/vendor?el=1%2E35239
/u-future/v1/fone?fhid=3028
/decline-summary/v1/details/card/65821974
/provide-service/v8/proDetails
/monetary-points/v1/sum/wins/681197
/listen-service/v1/audio-Details
/comment/v1/data
/comment/v1/data
/listen-service/v1/audio-Details
/comment/v1/data
/comment/v1/data
/listen-service/v1/audio-Details
/comment/v1/data
/comment/v1/data
```

Comment: What your regex purpose exactly? What it is looking and where?

Comment: the regex pattern should extract everything up to a '?' or digit or end of line. In that order if possible. So in example, the first string "/enterprise-review/v9/choose?rr=Straight&pr=1%2E35239" should only return "/enterprise-review/v9/choose". "/review-id-service/v1/business-id" should return itself "/review-id-service/v1/business-id" and "/vendor-service/v1/Product/PartnerId/35310108" should return "/vendor-service/v1/Product/PartnerId/"

Comment: This one more correct - `/(.*?/v\d/.*?((?=[\?\d\s])|$))` to match last line and various empty spaces after lines (which probably the reason why you don't catch some of them).

Comment: Can you change your question to include a runnable script?

Comment: @eocron , can you add this as an answer. This solved the problem. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one helped to resolve your issue:

```
/(.*?/v\d/.*?((?=[\?\d\s])|$))
```

The reason behind problem: probably `\r` (windows carriage return), whitespaces and also end of string (noted as `$` in regex).

Answer (score 1):

Here's your regex and input in regexstorm, a .net Rex tester:

[regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%2f%28.*%3f%2fv%5cd%2f.*%3f%28%28%3f%3d%5c%3f%29%7c%28%3f%3d%5cd%29%7c%28%3f%3d%5cn%29%29%29&i=%2fenterprise-review%2fv9%2fchoose%3frr%3dStraight%26pr%3d1%252E35239%0d%0a%2freview-id-service%2fv1%2fbusiness-id%0d%0a%2forderout%2fv1%2fvendor%2fshipping%0d%0a%2fvendor-service%2fv1%2fProduct%2fPartnerId%2f35310108%0d%0a%2fInspect%2fv1%2fRecommendation%2fProducts%2fLaneId%2f0002%2c519188%2c13148%2c16939%2c7348%2c195982%0d%0a%2fbin-inventory%2fv1%2fvendor%3fel%3d1%252E35239%0d%0a%2fu-future%2fv1%2ffone%3ffhid%3d3028%0d%0a%2fdecline-summary%2fv1%2fdetails%2fcard%2f65821974%0d%0a%2fprovide-service%2fv8%2fproDetails%0d%0a%2fmonetary-points%2fv1%2fsum%2fwins%2f681197%0d%0a%2flisten-service%2fv1%2faudio-Details%0d%0a%2fcomment%2fv1%2fdata%0d%0a%2fcomment%2fv1%2fdata%0d%0a%2flisten-service%2fv1%2faudio-Details%0d%0a%2fcomment%2fv1%2fdata%0d%0a%2fcomment%2fv1%2fdata%0d%0a%2flisten-service%2fv1%2faudio-Details%0d%0a%2fcomment%2fv1%2fdata%0d%0a%2fcomment%2fv1%2fdata)

I'd have made this a comment but RS's share urls contain the full Rex and input so it's too long for a comment (and SO doesn't allow url shorteners in comments)

So, my question is; does this look right to you? Are all the highlighted matches what you're expecting to match? If so, as RS's engine is .net based, I don't think there is a problem with the regex part of your code..

Comment: Those matches are exactly what I expect, and I can't seem to find an issue with the regex either. That is the source of my frustration.  The regex appears to be correct yet it doesn't match everything in the list when my code is executed. I did notice in the link that you provided that the very last line failed to match. Could there be a connection?

Comment: Last line doesn't match because it's not followed by a newline - it will if you put a return on it. In the panel at the bottom you'll find Tables, which shows all the things matched - it should contain all you seek, which makes me think the code that you have that iterates the matches is faulty (but I've never got into F# enough to read it)